# Modify 3D pie chart by adding value inside the pie

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I want to use highcharts,specifically 3D pie but I want to add different data to the pie chart (add values in the chart), something like this image:

[image]
Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Reading the docs (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie) and taking a look at the JSFiddle the docs point to (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-pie/) should give you all the information you need.

Comment: You need to define series object. More information here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series